# How to add a login screen in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to the xamarin platform and I am needing to achieve this screen in Xamarin Android.

[image]

Comment: This question would be better asked on [su].

Comment: @Blacksilver This question should be closed beacuse is out of topic, and It is based on opinions. Therefore, your comment is incorrect

Comment: @Blacksilver: I suspect the question is looking to develop a login screen, and so it would not be a good fit on _Super User_. Since it is far too brief to be clear, and it does not indicate any prior effort, so I don't think it is on-topic anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this popup when any button clicked or automatic when you go to login screen.

If you want this popup when button clicked then :
1- First Design this layout in your axml file.
2- On Button click create a Dialog.
3- Inflate that dialog with your created layout.

If You want this popup without any button click then in **OnCreate Method** follow above approach.

Comment: @SebastianMorgado If my Answer is usefull then Please give positive vote.